How to trigger `tenacity` retry without raising exception?
How can I trigger a retry within python tenacity library without raising an exception?
The reason I want this is that while debugging at every raise of an error, the debugger stops. (This can be switched off by unticking User Uncaught Exceptions (in VSCode), but that means the debugger doesn't stop at other errors either.)
I'd like to trigger the retry mechanism for tenacity without raising an error.
Is this possible?

I found one workaround with a type-checking compromise:
@retry(
    retry=retry_if_result(lambda x, **_: x is None),
)
def risky_function():
    ...
    if something_goes_wrong:
          return None

This is not great as the typechecker complains that None is not a valid return value.
